# Array Associate Cannot Pass All On Function When Associate Already Created

Tags: php, xampp, directory, php-node

I have a directory structure as shown below.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\rosoka\file
----- 2018-03-02
-------------test1.json
-------------test2.json
----- 2018-03-03
-------------test3.json
-------------test4.json
```

I want all my folders to be the key of an array associated like this on the last trace outside the function

```
Array ( [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file] => Array ( )) 
Array ( [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file/2018-03-02] => Array ()) 
Array ( [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file/2018-03-03] => Array ())
```

this is my **source code** please help me.

```
<?php
    $no_entity = array();
    listFolderFiles("C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file", $no_entity);
function listFolderFiles($dir, $no_entity){
        echo "<br>";
    if (array_key_exists($dir, $no_entity)) {
        echo "why no result here??? T_T";
    } else {
        $no_entity[$dir] = array();
        print_r($no_entity);
    }
    $real_path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file";
    $real_path =  str_replace($real_path,"",$dir);
    set_time_limit (3000000);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
    $ffs = array_values($ffs);
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
       if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
            listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, $no_entity); 
        } else { 
        }
    }
}
    //  "WHERE MY ARRAY T_T";
    var_dump($no_entity);   
?>
```

(for testing ekstract to htdocs)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dtXbQFrWoD0dQFOb-2YRqcH4eKPUTzZ9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the sample data (i.e. actual directory listing where you test your code), what are the expected results, and what are the actual results?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dtXbQFrWoD0dQFOb-2YRqcH4eKPUTzZ9/view?usp=sharing thx for answer sir, my expectation on var_dump

Comment: The google drives links are not previewing correctly.

Comment: i friends can download sir

Answer (score 1):

Without some better examples of your folder structure and what you are wanting from it, this is my best guess.

This will take folders found in the directory and create an array like you have posted.

```
$path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file';
$dir = glob($path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach($dir as $d => $val){

  $results[][$val]  = array();

}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: yes correctly like that result, but with loop function sir
i will explore more glob() and combine with my code 
thx before

Comment: Glad it helped you out.  Glob is very useful for getting folders and files.